# Prove that $\sigma(AB) \backslash \{0\} = \sigma(BA)\backslash \{0\} $

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Prove that $\sigma(AB) \backslash \{0\} = \sigma(BA)\backslash \{0\} $.
Where $A,\ B$ are bounded operators in Banach space and $\sigma$ denotes spectrum.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a classic (I learned this from Appendix A, A.1 of G.K. Pedersen, *[$C^{\ast}$-algebras and their automorphism groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=yBCoAAAAIAAJ)*, see also [exercise 4.1.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=a1R0livwR9AC&pg=PA133) in his *[Analysis Now](http://books.google.com/books?id=a1R0livwR9AC)* — thanks, w(ild)<sup>3</sup>life):

> Let $\mathcal A$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with a unit (here $\mathcal{A}$ is the algebra of bounded linear operators on your Banach space). Then $\sigma(AB) \smallsetminus \{0\} = \sigma(BA) \smallsetminus \{0\}$.

If $\lambda \notin \sigma(AB) \cup \{0\}$ then there is $C$ such that
$$
C(\lambda - AB) = 1 = (\lambda-AB)C.
$$
Then verify that $\lambda^{-1}(1 + BCA)$ is the inverse of $(\lambda-BA)$ so that $\lambda \notin \sigma(BA) \cup \{0\}$:
$$
(1 + BCA)(\lambda-BA) = \lambda = (\lambda-BA)(1+BCA),
$$
as a straightforward computation shows.

---

**Later:**

There's a nice mnemonic on how to guess the inverse, also addressed in-depth [in this MO-thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/) by Bill Dubuque:

Recall the geometric series $(1-q)^{-1} = 1 + q + q^2 + \cdots$, so formally
$$\begin{align*}
(1-BA)^{-1} &= 1+ BA + BABA + BABABA + \cdots \\
&= 1 + B(1+ AB+ ABAB + \cdots)A \\
&= 1 + B(1-AB)^{-1}A \\
& = 1+BCA
\end{align*}$$
with $C = (1-AB)^{-1}$.
Similarly with $(\lambda-AB)^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this problem here before, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You may also be interested in having a look at [this MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/how-would-you-solve-this-tantalizing-halmos-problem) started by Bill Dubuque.

Comment: Is a $\mathbb C = C^*$? Never seen that notation.

Comment: @Jonas: A $\mathbb{C}$-algebra is an algebra over the field of complex numbers (as in "$k$-algebra over a commutative ring $k$"): a complex vector space equipped with a bilinear and associative multiplication. The spectrum of an element of a unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra is $$\sigma(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : \lambda - A \text{ is not invertible}\}.$$

Comment: How to prove that $\lambda^{-1}(\lambda - BCA)$ is the inverse of $\lambda - BA$

Comment: @Philipp: Sorry, there were some silly typos $$(1+BCA)(\lambda-BA) = \lambda - BA + B[C(\lambda - AB)]A = \lambda$$ and similarly for the other side.

Comment: This is also exercise E.4.1.3 (page 133) of Pederson's Anaylsis NOW (his hint is the answer).

Comment: @wildildildlife: thanks, I forgot about that, so maybe I learned it there... Anyway, I learned it from Pedersen :)