# Spectrum of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\sigma(AB) \backslash \{0\} = \sigma(BA)\backslash \{0\} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79217/prove-that-sigmaab-backslash-0-sigmaba-backslash-0)

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a (complex) Hilbert space. I want to prove that $\sigma(AA^*)=\sigma(A^*A)$, where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the spectrum. The finite dimensional case is (almost) trivial. How could we extend to infinite dimensional case? (Maybe a reference is appreciated.)
(I tried to find the answer, but search engine cannot handle formula.)

Comment: That's wrong. Conside $\ell^2$ and $A\colon (x_n) \mapsto (0, x_1, \ldots)$. Then $A^*\colon (x_n) \mapsto (x_2, \ldots)$. So $AA^*\colon (x_n) \mapsto (0, x_2, \ldots)$ and $A^*A = \mathrm{id}$. Hence $0 \in \sigma(AA^*) \setminus \sigma(A^*A)$. But you will allways have $\sigma(AA^*)\setminus \{0\} = \sigma(A^*A) \setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: More generally you have $\sigma(AB) \smallsetminus \{0\} = \sigma(BA) \smallsetminus \{0\}$ whenever $A,B$ are elements of a unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. See e.g. [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/79217)

Comment: Thanks the link and the counterexample. I'm awfully sorry, I forgot to write that A is invertible. In this case the above equality is valid, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is valid (sorry for the late response): $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^\ast$ is invertible, thus $A^\ast A$ and $AA^\ast$ are both invertible, so $0$ doesn't belong to neither $\sigma(AA^\ast)$ nor to $\sigma(A^\ast A)$ and hence the spectra are equal.