# Prove that if $I-BA$ is invertible then $I-AB$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> Prove that if $I-BA$ is invertible then $I-AB$ is invertible.

Though I have found this question already posted and  also it has some answers like

*Use*:$(I−BA)(I+B(I−AB)^{−1}A)=I(I−BA)(I+B(I−AB)^{−1}A)=I $

I have done it like this.

$I-BA$ is invertible $\implies 0$ is not an eigen value of $I-BA\implies 1$  is not an eigen value of $BA\implies 1$ is not an eigen value of $AB\implies 0$ is not an eigen value of $I-AB\implies I-AB$ is invertible.

I have used the facts the

1. $AB,BA$ have same non-zero eigen values

**Proof**:Let $c\neq 0$ be a eigen value of $AB$ corresponding to eigen vector $\alpha$.Then $A(B\alpha)=c\alpha$

Now $(BA)(B\alpha)=B(AB\alpha)=c(B\alpha)\implies c$ is an eigen vector of $BA$ corresponding to $B\alpha$.Also $B\alpha\neq 0$ otherwise $c=0$ .

Similarly every eigen value of $BA$ is an eigen value of $AB$.

**How to show that they have same eigen values for if $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices?**

and

2. If $c$ is an eigen value of a matrix $M$, then $1-c$ is an eigen value of $I-M$.

Please check whether my answer is correct/not.

Comment: Hm, I actually learned this yesterday. But this is due to Sylvester's determinant identity, or I should say it's a one-liner if you use this.

Comment: @Nameless that doesn't address the actual question

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, re-read. Looks like he just wants to check.

Comment: Related question you mention can be this one: [$I-AB$ be invertible $\Leftrightarrow$ $I-BA$ is invertible](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365837/i-ab-be-invertible-leftrightarrow-i-ba-is-invertible)

Comment: [Here is an easy way](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1080076/242) to *discover* the identity used in the first proof, It is a famous Halmos problem to [explain why this power series proof works.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/675128/242)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, what you call the "use" of this fact is sufficient for a proof.

However, your steps are indeed (mostly) correct.  As long as you and the reader can agree to take for granted that $AB$ and $BA$ share their *non-zero eigenvalues* (which is a non-trivial statement to make), then this proof is valid.  Note that, depending on your professor, this might not be sufficient detail for a proof on a test.

Note that $AB$ and $BA$ do not necessarily share *all* of their eigenvalues unless they happen to be square.  It is possible for $AB$ to be invertible without $BA$ being invertible.

Comment: Yes I have proved that $AB$ and $BA$ have same non-zero eigen values; :I have added a proof also

Comment: But how can I show that if $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices then they have the same eigen values

Comment: @BobWilson it suffices to note that, in this case,
$$
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = \det(BA)
$$

Comment: @BobWilson in the future, rather than adding a question to your original post (which has already been answered), it is better to start a new post.

Comment: Yes that's true but it would add another question to the already existing bunch of questions ;so I thought it to be a better idea