# Prove that $AB=BA$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space

> Let $A,B\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$. Assume that there exists $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $AB=zBA$. Why
>   $$AB=BA\;?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $AB=0$ or $BA=0$, you are done. Otherwise, from $BA=|z|^2BA$, you obtain that $|z|=1$.

We have $$\{0\}\cup\sigma(BA)=\{0\}\cup\sigma(AB)=\{0\}\cup\sigma(zBA)
=\{0\}\cup z\,\sigma(BA). 
$$
So $$\tag1\lambda\in\sigma(BA)\iff z\lambda\in\sigma(BA).$$ 
We also have, using that [$\{0\}\cup\sigma(TS)=\{0\}\cup\sigma(ST)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79217/prove-that-sigmaab-backslash-0-sigmaba-backslash-0),
$$\tag2
\{0\}\cup\sigma(BA)=\{0\}\cup\sigma(B^{1/2}(B^{1/2}A))=\{0\}\cup\sigma(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})\subset[0,\infty).
$$
Note that $\sigma(BA)\ne\{0\}$. Because if $\sigma(BA)=\{0\}$, then (2) gives $\sigma(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})=\{0\}$; but this is a positive operator, so we would get $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}=0$, which is the same as $(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})^*A^{1/2}B^{1/2}=0$, so $A^{1/2}B^{1/2}=0$ which in turn gives $AB=0$, and then $BA=0$.

Now, using $(2)$, take $\lambda>0$ with $\lambda\in \sigma(BA)$. Then, from $(1)$,  $z\lambda\in(0,\infty)$, which implies $z\in (0,\infty)$. So $z$ is a positive real number with $|z|=1$, i.e. $z=1$.

Comment: Please why you have shown that $\sigma(BA)\ne\{0\}$?. Because I think that even if $BA\neq 0$ which has a nontrivial kernel then 0 will be in its spectrum.

Comment: $\sigma(BA)\ne\{0\}$ does **not** preclude  $0\in\sigma(BA)$.

Comment: But why you have shown that $\sigma(BA)\ne\{0\}$? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Because if I cannot use a nonzero $\lambda$, I cannot gather much information from $z\lambda$.